# PDO PHP Mysql slow on particular query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a real strange problem using PDO for Mysql in php.

I have a table with about 30,000 rows in it.

If I try and run this query:

> SELECT card_data.name, max(card_data.set_order) FROM card_data,
>   theme_decks  WHERE card_data.name = 'Mana Leak' and card_data.enabled
>   = 1 GROUP BY card_data.name  ORDER BY card_data.name

(How its made)

```
SELECT card_data.name, max(card_data.set_order) FROM card_data, theme_decks  
WHERE card_data.name = ? and
card_data.enabled = 1 GROUP BY card_data.name  ORDER BY card_data.name ASC

$paramArray = array("Mana Leak");
$sth->execute($paramArray);
```

Through PDO it takes around 10 seconds execute!! Yet if i run the same query though phpmyadmin it takes less than a second..

The weird part is this query below will take less than a second though PDO:

```
SELECT card_data.name, max(card_data.set_order) FROM card_data, theme_decks  WHERE 
(card_data.name = 'Extraplanar Lens' OR card_data.name = 'Mana Leak' OR card_data.name = 
'overgrowth')  and card_data.enabled = 1 GROUP BY card_data.name  ORDER BY card_data.name ASC
```

(How its made)

```
  SELECT card_data.name, max(card_data.set_order) FROM card_data, theme_decks  WHERE 
    (card_data.name = ? OR card_data.name = ? OR card_data.name = 
    ?)  and card_data.enabled = 1 GROUP BY card_data.name  ORDER BY card_data.name ASC

    $paramArray = array("Extraplanar Lens","Mana Leak","overgrowth");
    $sth->execute($paramArray);
```

I can't for the life of me workout why searching for a single "name" would take 10 seconds when searching for multiple names only takes about 0.4 of a second...

EDIT: Plot thickens. I removed the parameterized statement and hardcoded the text to search

```
SELECT card_data.name, max(card_data.set_order) FROM card_data, theme_decks WHERE
card_data.name = Mana Leak and card_data.enabled = 1 GROUP BY card_data.name ORDER BY 
card_data.name ASC
```

Takes 0.000384092330933 seconds to query with PDO!!

BUT

```
SELECT card_data.name, max(card_data.set_order) FROM card_data, theme_decks WHERE
card_data.name = 'Mana Leak' and card_data.enabled = 1 GROUP BY card_data.name ORDER BY 
card_data.name ASC
```

Takes 11.00254 seconds to to query with PDO!!

Comment: is there any field inside your table card_data.name?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? The field is name in the table card_data

Comment: Just out of interest, if you store the query within a stored procedure and run that both via PDO and PHPMyAdmin, do you get the same delay?

Comment: Good question. I shall find out!

Comment: since you have used only one table card_data then why do you confuse the by referencing again,, by its name from card_data that alone enough for sure ! D:

Comment: the table themeDecks also has a field named name and it would cause conflicts

Comment: It's likely faster when running the query the second time (from PHPMyAdmin) thanks to caching. The query time can sometimes be deceiving. Ensure that you use EXPLAIN and SHOW PROFILE to profile a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slow usually means you need indexes. I see you have a `max()` function on the `card_data.set_order`. This would mean your database has to go over every record to find the biggest.

See if there is an Index on that field. If not, add one and see if that improves it

Comment: Adding the index worked perfectly! Thanks very much. Though I'm still a bit confused about why there was nearly 300x difference between searching for a single "name" and searching for multiple names!

Comment: I actually added the index to the name field fyi thats what fixed it. Just re-reading what you said and was you suggesting to add it to the card_data.set_order field?

Comment: Yes, generally using a field in a WHERE clause should ring the index bell. But MAX() is a function that has to go over every record to find the maximum function. You can run "EXPLAIN SELECT ...." in phpmyadmin to determine the efficiency of your query and see what I mean